# Create a Drupal View of current event participant numbers

Tags: civievent, drupal, drupal-views

We use CiviCRM to sell event tickets and I was wondering if it's possible to pull the list of current events and confirmed participant number in to a simple Drupal View restricted to logged in users so we can keep track of ticket sales more easily?

I've looked at the built in options for creating the views but can't see a way of pulling that data across.

If there's an easier way of doing this directly in Civi then all ears for that as well but we're finding it a bit clunky to have to find each individual event each time and check the registered participant number and just want an overview.

Comment: Do you want to clarify what it is about the Event Dashboard that does not provide the overview you want? Too many current events? eg http://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/event?reset=1 - otherwise concur with Karin - a view based on Participants using Aggregation i think would give you the summary counts if you need to go via Views

Comment: We've done this with Views and Aggregator Plus, exactly as Pete says. This lists all upcoming events, with their current bookings and links to their participant lists. I can send you screen shots or a view export if that's helpful. J

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do this in a Drupal View but it will require some config (both to tell Drupal about your CiviCRM tables as well as the Views config itself);

The goto solution for this within CiviCRM itself is:

Install: Extended Report Extension: 
Got to your Adminster -> System -> Settings -> Manage Extensions -> Add New -> ExtendedReport (nz.co.fuzion.extendedreport)

After you've installed it -> go Administer -> CiviReport -> Create New Report from Template and select e.g. Extended Report - Contributions with Price Set data